# WP7: How to debug application when it is started by Secondary Tile of phone's start page?

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7

I have an application which can create Secondary Tile on start page. I need to debug application when it is run from that tile. How to do that?

Comment: I believe if you just launch it from visual studio and then go to home on the emulator and don't exit from the debugger, and then open it up again it should still be debugging. Not sure if that works for secondary tile but I think it works like that for when you reopen it.

Comment: When I go to home, VS is still in debugging mode. When I push Secondary Tile it is still in debugging mode but not in mine (breakpoints do not stop application). So the solution is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do this debugging by changing the entry in the WMAppManifest.xml file to a xaml address which matches the secondary tile:

e.g. I change

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />
```

to:

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MyDeepLinkPage.xaml?SpecialId=1234" />
```

---

If you don't want to do it in Xaml then you could also intercept the RootFrame's navigating event in your app.xaml.cs code

Comment: If you don't want to do it in Xaml then you can also intercept the RootFrame's navigating event in your app.xaml.cs code